# Inheritance and the constructor chain with native duktape/C functions

Tags: duktape

Using native functions to implement a class constructor is [described in the duktape wiki](http://wiki.duktape.org/HowtoNativeConstructor.html). What's left out there however is how to implement a class hierarchy.

When your native constructor is called for a derived class, how do you handle the inheritance chain in duktape? In Javascript you would usually do something like:

```
function Base(){
}

...

function SubClass(){
    // Call super constructor.
    Base.call(this);
}
```

How would you implement that in duktape? We cannot use [duk_call()](http://duktape.org/api.html#duk_call) since we don't have a method to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the same behavior as in the Ecmascript example, you would do something like:

```
duk_get_global_string(ctx, "Base");
duk_push_this(ctx);
duk_call_method(ctx, 0);  /* = Base.call(this) */
```

Comment: Interesting here is that this code will call the native constructor function with `duk_is_constructor_call()` returning `false`, which produces extra trouble. Any idea how we can accept it in cases of inheritance calls, but not in general?

Comment: That C snippet should work the same as the Ecmascript example in the question -- `Base.call(this)`. Prior to ES6 there's no way to do a `super()` call. Once that is implemented in Duktape, it will also be exposed to C code but it's not supported yet and thus there is also no C equivalent.